# L'expression "à la Saint-Glinglin"

Tags: genre, locutions, noms-propres

> Je te rendrai ton argent à la Saint-Glinglin.
>
> Les paysans avaient l’habitude de payer leurs dettes après leur récolte (moisson, vendange…). Ils payaient donc par exemple à la Saint-Michel… mais pas à la Saint-Glinglin.

Je connais le sens de la locution (synonyme de "remettre aux calendes grecques"). Je me demande pourquoi *à la* et pas *au* Saint-Glinglin.

Comment: glinglin is cute and comical and rhymes with saint, rhymes are catchy because they effectivelyimplant in memoery sebconciously, i.e. firm names cola fORd escORt jaI zI do better than triangle bleu.

Comment: C'est la même chose pour toutes les fêtes du calendrier qui célèbrent un saint : _La saint Barthélémy_, _la saint Matthieu_, ... La question devrait peut-être être tournée dans ce sens général plutôt que centrée sur la saint Glinglin, non ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Une page chez Druide](https://www.druide.com/fr/enquetes/temps-des-f%C3%AAtes-temps-des-fautes), éditeur de nombreux outils linguistiques et dictionnaires, explique que pour les jours des saints, le terme *fête* est sous-entendu, et qu’on les désigne donc au féminin.

> **La « sainte » règle.** - Quand on parle d'un *saint*, le mot saint s'écrit avec une minuscule et sans trait d'union *(la vie de saint Sylvestre)* ; quand on parle du jour mis sous la protection du saint, le mot *saint* s'écrit avec la majuscule et un trait d'union *(le jour, la fête de la Saint-Sylvestre)*. Bref : la fête de saint Sylvestre se célèbre le jour de la Saint-Sylvestre.
> **Genre.** - Féminin. Puisque le mot *fête* est sous-entendu, les noms des fêtes des saints sont toujours féminins, peu importe le sexe du personnage honoré : *la Saint-Nicolas, fêtée le 6 décembre, honore saint Nicolas, patron des petits enfants et ancêtre du père Noël.*

Et donc, ***la** Saint-Glinglin* sous-entend la ***fête** de saint Glinglin*.

---

#### Mais...

Bien que l’on trouve de nombreux exemples très communément utilisés en langue française (***la** Saint-Jean le 24 juin, **la** Saint-Valentin le 14 février, **la** Saint-Patrick le 17 mars, etc.)*, cette explication ne clarifie pas entièrement la question. Par exemple, dans le premier paragraphe, on mentionne...

> la fête de la Saint-Sylvestre

Si le premier ***la*** est bien mis pour indiquer le féminin du mot ***fête*** qui le suit, la seconde marque du féminin qui introduit ***Saint-Sylvestre***, à la lumière des informations fournies, serait mise car on sous-entend *fête*. Pourrait-on donc avoir un déploiement en poupée russe de l’expression ?

> **la fête de la** fête de la <sub>fête de la <sub>fête de la</sub></sub> [etc.] **Saint-Sylvestre**

Une piste d’explication pourrait être envisagée si l’on décide de comprendre que l’on parle des [**festivités**](http://cnrtl.fr/synonymie/f%C3%AAte) survenant le jour de la fête du saint. Mais on se retrouve toujours coincés à un moment entre deux feux : soit on réintroduit sans fin l’article ***la*** dans le déploiement, soit on le retire, mais on doit alors réorthographier le bout final. D’une expression comme **les festivités de la Saint-Sylvestre** on aboutit à :

> **les festivités de la** fête de la <sub>fête de la <sub>fête de la</sub></sub> [etc.] **Saint-Sylvestre**

...ou à :

> **les festivités de la** fête de saint Sylvestre

En définitive, il est bien possible que l’on ait chez Druide davantage une explication de l’usage qu’une règle rigoureusement construite. Cette règle existe-t-elle ailleurs, cependant ? Je ne le sais pas.

Comment: cp. also ["La brunette est là"](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=hTEG6Z_wkcA) : "Le jour de la Saint-Pierre pis aussi de la Saint-Jean" :)